# linux command to get info from a line

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file in linux which contains my application's log. With grep I get the wanted lines but I need to process them in order to get only specific value. More exactly I have the next log:

```
13 Jan 2014 15:22:18,291 DEBUG some data
13 Jan 2014 15:22:18,291 DEBUG some data
13 Jan 2014 15:22:18,291 DEBUG <request><object>3</object></request>
13 Jan 2014 15:22:18,291 DEBUG <request><object>4</object></request>
13 Jan 2014 15:22:18,291 DEBUG <request><object>5</object></request>
13 Jan 2014 15:22:18,291 DEBUG more data
```

With the next command I get the log lines with the XML:

`grep \<request\> myLog.log`

However I only want `<object>` value. Normally I make this kind of things with `awk` however I only use this command to work with lines which has columns and I don't know how to achieve this, can someone put me on the right direction? There is a better command to do so that `awk`?

Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks guys, I like the two answers... I can't choose both so finally I choose the first one due being the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
awk -F"[<>]" '/<request>/ {print $5}' file
3
4
5
```

---

If number of field may vary, then this `awk` prints only value after `<object>`

```
awk -F"><object>" '/<request>/ {split($2,a,"<");print a[1]}' file
3
4
5
```

Or like this:

```
awk -F"><object>" '/<request>/ {print $2+0}' file
3
4
5
```

Comment: it should be `print $5`

Comment: @Vor A small typo, fixed.

Comment: why not use `<request><object>` as `FS`? :-)

Comment: @Kent It may be done, but what if there are other parameter inn between.  It will then fail. Eks one line `<request><object>` other `<request><master><object>`.  The last two `awk` will search for all lines with `<request>` and print any value after `<object>` regardless of location on the line.

Comment: `+$2` will only concert a string to a number on some awks (e.g. it will not work in nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk) and it's semantics are ambiguous (e.g. try concatenating using `print "x" +$2` vs `print "x" $2+0`) so always use `$2+0` instead of `+$2`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the lesson.  I will for sure drop use of `+$2`, updated my post.

Comment: @Jotne `-F` is the way then I can use whatever separator! thanks now I get it :).

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -oP '<request><object>\K[^<]*' file
```

GNU grep with perl-compatible regex

Comment: This does not take care if its a line with `reqest` or not.

Comment: +1 I feel grep is the tool for this job. if OP's grep supported lookbehind.

Comment: @AvinashRaj  You do not edit someones code to make it do some different than was intended.  You may make a comment, and then it up to poster to change it. -1 to you.

Comment: @Jotne Was that `-1` in form of promissory note? `:P`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, quite right, the OP did specifically grep for "request" lines.

Comment: @glennjackman I don't know that this was possible with grep, and also I never use before the `\K` for regex, so I learn two things +1!! :).

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, you can try to match for <object> or </object>, capture it and then print the second column of that capture (behind the first captured <object>):

```
$ awk -F'</?object>' 'NF>1{print $2}' file
```

Comment: in my case check the number of records is not necessary (`NF>1`) because if `</?object>` not match any separator there is nothing to print in `$2`. Thanks anyway for the answer and to teach me the `NF`. +1!

Comment: The `NF>1` is so you don't get a blank line printed when `</?object>` doesn't match.